# How to conditionally add css properties in jquery (coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have the following coffeescript code at the top in document ready so it should be run on load. I need to get the username loaded from a Ruby variable and only highlight red if that username matches the username of a comment so the user can only delete their own comments.

```
if $(".comment-username").html() == username
    $('.comment-entry').addClass('user-comments')
```

My haml looks like this:

```
%p{:class => "comment-entry"}
  %b{:class=> "comment-username"}= comment.username
  = comment.text
```

The css looks like:

```
.user-comments:hover{
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

It seems that no comments are being selected and changed, even though several are the same as the username (which is fetched by a hidden value)

Is there anything wrong with my code that could cause this behavior?

Comment: "which is fetched by a hidden value" Is .comment-username a hidden input field? If so use `$(".comment-username").val()`.  Otherwise, you want to use `$(".comment-username").text().trim()` instead of html() to determine the underlying string

Comment: The username is fine and is in a hidden div, I use the a regex to get rid of any whitespace or returns and it has been tested to work in other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason this was not working is that I was only calling the selector once instead of for each time an instance of that class appeared. Also I had some inheritance issues like selecting the username which was within the entry that needed to be fixed. Here is the correct working code:

```
$('.comment-entry').each (index) ->
  if $(this).find('.comment-username').html() == username
    $(this).addClass('user-comments')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a class via JS, you can do it faster while generating your html document and get rid of JS.
Assuming you have access to `@current_user` variable in your view which stores current logged in user and a method `name` which stores a username of a user:

```
%p{:class => "comment-entry #{comment.username == @current_user.name ? 'user-comments' : ''}"}
  %b{:class=> "comment-username"}= comment.username
  = comment.text
```

Comment: This is slick with the class in a Ruby string, but not the reason it was failing. +1

Comment: this is not working for me>> `className: "form-inline collapse #{@state.collapseClassPresent == true ? 'in' : ''}"` and is generateing the following JS code `className: "form-inline " + " collapse " + ((ref = this.state.collapseClassPresent === true) != null ? ref : {'in': ''})`